# Determine Error/Exception Type Python

Tags: python, error-handling

I am using the win32Com module to write data to an excel sheet on a Windows 7 machine with Python 3.5. While it is running I get thrown an error. I tried making a "try/except" block but the error type I attempted is apparently not an actual error type. Here is my code :

```
import win32com.client as win32
import sqlite3

def writeWords(storage):
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
i = 0 
storLen = len(storage)
while i < storLen:
    varX = storage[i]
    lenVar = len(varX)
    q = 0 
    while q < lenVar:
        tarf = str(storage[i][q].encode('ascii', errors='ignore')).lstrip("b\'").rstrip("\'")
        try :
            ws.Cells(q+1,i+1).Value = (tarf)
        except pywintypes.com_error:
            print("Error")
            q +=1
        q += 1
    i += 1
```

The traceback I get is this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LewTo002\Google Drive\Todd's Stuff\python\mailWords\current\mailWords2.py", line 65, in writeWords
    ws.Cells(q+1,i+1).Value = (tarf)
  File "C:\Users\LewTo002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 474, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146777998), None)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LewTo002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec(codeObject, __main__.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\LewTo002\Google Drive\Todd's Stuff\python\mailWords\current\mailWords2.py", line 100, in <module>
    writeWords(storage)
  File "C:\Users\LewTo002\Google Drive\Todd's Stuff\python\mailWords\current\mailWords2.py", line 66, in writeWords
    except pywintypes.com_error:
NameError: name 'pywintypes' is not defined
```

I am used to seeing things like here ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy ) and have been basing my method of writing the try/except off of here ( https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html )

My question is how do I determine the error type that I am trying to catch based on the top portion of the traceback?

Comment: Could you show your imports please?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't import `pywintypes`.

Comment: I've added my imports to the main post. You are correct in that I didn't import pywintypes. I will import that and try again to see what happens. Thanks user235!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an import, more specifically

```
from pywintypes import com_error
```

then use the following

```
except com_error as e:
```

Comment: ,thanks for the more clear answer. I am not sure what "as e:" is in your suggestion though, what is the purpose of it? Thank you very much for the information!

Comment: @ToddLewden that assigns the Error object to the name `e`. It's helpful for parsing the error message.

Comment: What @DavidZemmens said. If you want to extract information from the Error object, this assigns it to a variable. It is also common practice.

Answer (score 0):

By importing "pywintypes" my error try/except functions properly.